# how to handle ajax resonseText with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have gotten my form to post with ajax, and all works well. As far as ajax is concerned, it processed its job successfully with a responseText. But that doesn't mean that everything processed correctly in my case.

ajax is posting my form which runs a php file to insert data into my database. Success or fail, there will be a responseText that either says: "Thank you" if all data was inserted into db, or "Err:" if it failed.

How do I make an if condition from that responseText to handle that kind of custom responseText error? Or can I force it to return an .ajaxError() upon the responseText of "Err:"?

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="contact">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="required email" name="email"  maxlength="30" value="youremail @ example.com" />
        <input type="text" id="subject" class="required" name="subject" maxlength="24" value="Enter your subject" />
        <textarea id="msg" class="required textarea" name="msg" cols="30" rows="5">Reason for contact.</textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="formBtn" value="Punch me an Email" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#contact').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit:formValidate, 
        success: showResponse,
        clearForm:true
    }); 
});
function formValidate(){
    $('#contact').validate({
                rules:{
                    email:{required: true, email:true},
                    subject:{required: true, minlength: 5},
                    msg:{required: true, minlength: 50}
                },
                messages:{
                    email:'',
                    subject: '',
                    msg: ''
                },
                invalidHandler:function(){
                    $('div.error').hide();
                },
                focusInvalid:true,
                onfocusout:false,
                submitHandler: function() {
                    $('#contact').ajaxSubmit();
               }
            });
}
function showResponse(responseText,statusText,xhr,$form){
    console.log(responseText);
//    alert(responseText);
    // $("#contact").toggle('slow');
}
```

Comment: There we go. Sorry forgot to put code on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding the `dataType: 'json'` property to your `$.ajaxForm` call. Then in your php instead of returning 'Thanks' you can return:

```
return json(array('status'=>'success'));
```

or

```
return json(array('status'=>'failed'));
```

Then in show-response you can run something like :

```
if(responseText.status === 'failed') { // do something })
```

Comment: This works great, but i had to print it out in php to get a responseText. If i told it to return a json_encode(array), i'd get nothing returned.

Comment: sorry, I'm so used to working with a certain framework... Yes, you need to print it out.. you may also need to set the appropriate Content-type header for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get your PHP to send an error string such that it appears in responseText. Then in your JavaScript code, you'll have to interpret that error string. It won't be an AJAX error because, as far as AJAX is concerned, everything worked beautifully. AJAX doesn't know that your program found an error; it only knows that it sent a request and got a response back.

To put it another way: the separation of powers and responsibilities between AJAX and your program means that AJAX isn't allowed to intervene in your program's operation.

Comment: Right, so I can see in the alert or console.log that it returns success or error messages, but I can't seem to get an condition out of that responseText. I've tried using the responseText.Search("Error"), but that breaks my whole js validation process.

Comment: @robx: Did you try `if (responseText == "Error") /* foo */`?

Comment: @robx -- it looks like responseText is empty. What did you see when you uncommented "alert (responseText);"?

Comment: i get the responsetext i want, but i am testing different methods to see what works best at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you detect an error server side, have your php code set the response status to 500 and return your error message. That will trigger ajaxForm's error callback.

I'm not a PHP guy so I'm not sure how you'd set your response to 500, but I use this method with Asp.net and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I used to return 200 regardless if an error occured or not, and I was returning an error code by returning different string messages but that was not a good practice according to RESTful structures. [Here's a link](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2003/12/restful_error_handling.html) about what I'm referring to.

So, throwing an appropriate exception at your serverside code seems to be the best practice.

> throw new Exception('Division by
>   zero.');

When that happens, your ajax client would get a response with Http Status Code (500). Jquery understands and triggers the error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) event using this Status code (which is 500=internal server error), and it would return your custom exception details.

Then, you can parse these 3 parameters and give a proper response to your client.